# Convert string to js map

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, dictionary

I am doing a ajax post and getting this date back from the server (I have control of the server if I need to make changes):

```
"[{4e2384d1eca4a61030d8746c:'27.7766405735821,-81.9141438476562,stuff,'},{4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7:'27.94904038727,-82.6213887207031,test again,'}]"
```

I am trying to convert it to a map ie

```
{4e2384d1eca4a61030d8746c:'27.7766405735821,-81.9141438476562,stuff,'}
{4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7:'27.94904038727,-82.6213887207031,test again,'}
```

in Firebug where I receive the data I am doing a watch of

```
$.parseJSON(txt)  //where txt is the data received
```

but I get an error

> ```
> Invalid JSON:
> ```
>
> [{4e2384d1eca4a61030d8746c:'27.7766405735821,-81.9141438476562,stuff,'},{4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7:'27.94904038727,-82.6213887207031,test
>   again,'}]

TIA

Comment: Obviously you are not creating proper JSON... what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't make it valid JSON by using double quotes around the keys and string values:

```
'[{"4e2384d1eca4a61030d8746c":"27.7766405735821,-81.9141438476562,stuff,"},{"4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7":"27.94904038727,-82.6213887207031,test again,"}]'
```

...then you may be stuck with `eval()`, but you should *only* use it if you're absolutely certain the data is secure.

```
var result;
eval( 'result=' + txt );
```